# Flutter FCM works for sometime then stops working

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Firebase Notification and I have observed that I get notifications in all scenarios (foregorund,background,terminated) but then after sometime, I do not receive any notifications until I close the app and open it. I am not sure what the issue is and how to solve it.

Here's my **main.dart** file.

```
AndroidNotificationChannel channel;
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
 final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: "Main Navigator");
 Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
   flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channel.description,
                icon: '@drawable/splash',
                playSound: true
              ),
            ));
            navigatorKey.currentState
                      .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OrdersScreen()));
}



Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'high_importance_channel', // id
      'High Importance Notifications', // title
      'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
      importance: Importance.high,
    );
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  await DotEnv.load(fileName: ".env");

 
  
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _isLoading;
  var appUpdate;

  void initState(){ 
    super.initState();
    var initializationSettingsAndroid  = AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/splash');
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(android:initializationSettingsAndroid);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
     FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage()
        .then((RemoteMessage message) {
      if (message != null) {
          navigatorKey.currentState
                       .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OrdersScreen()));
      }
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      print('Inside onmessage'); 
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {

        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channel.description,
                icon: '@drawable/splash',
                playSound: true
              ),
            ));
     AwesomeDialog(
              context: navigatorKey.currentContext,
              dismissOnTouchOutside:false,
              dialogType: DialogType.SUCCES,
              animType: AnimType.TOPSLIDE,
              title: 'You have received a new order',
              desc: notification.body,      
              btnCancelOnPress: () {
              },
              btnOkText: "Go to Orders",
              btnCancelText:"Cancel",
              btnOkOnPress: () {
                  setState(() {
                  navigatorKey.currentState
                       .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OrdersScreen()));
              });
              }
          )..show();
      }
    });
  }
  
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {     
    return !(_isLoading)?MultiProvider(
      providers: [
       ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => Auth(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
          create:null,
          update:(ctx,auth, previousProducts) => Products(auth.token, 
          
        auth.userId)), 
         
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => Cart(),
        ),
        
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => ColorChanger(),
        ),
    ],   
        child: Consumer<Auth>(builder: (ctx, auth, _) => 
          MaterialApp( 
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,    
        title: 'MyApp',
        theme: ThemeData(
           textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
            bodyColor: Colors.black,
            displayColor: Colors.black,
            ),
          primaryColor:  Colors.white,
          accentColor:  Color(0xFFF2AD18),
          fontFamily: 'Muli',
        ),
        home: 
              auth.isAuthauth.isAuth
        CategoriesScreen()
         : FutureBuilder(
                      future: auth.tryAutoLogin(),
                      builder: (ctx, authResultSnapshot) =>
                          authResultSnapshot.connectionState ==
                                  ConnectionState.waiting
                              ?  Center(
                                    child: Loading(),
                                )
                              : LoginPage(),
        ),
        routes: {
          ProductDetailScreen.routeName:(ctx) => ProductDetailScreen(),
          CartScreen.routeName: (ctx) => CartScreen(),
        }
      ),
        ) 
    ):Center(child:Loading());
  }
}
```

Here's my cloud function:

```
/* eslint-disable */ 
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();  
const db = admin.firestore();
exports.printitemcreated = functions.database.ref('/orders/{userId}/{orderId}')
    .onCreate(async(snapshot, context) => {
      
      const original = snapshot.val();
            const querySnapshot = await db
            .collection('users')
            .doc('123456')  
            .collection('tokens')
            .get();
      
          const tokens = querySnapshot.docs.map(snap => snap.id);
          await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens,{ 
              notification: {
                  title: 'You have new order!',
                  body: `Order #  ${original.uniqueOrderNumber}`,
                  click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
                }
          });    
         
      return;
    });
```